# Problem with maxium likelihood estimator for a lognormal

Tags: statistics

I need to calculate the mean estimator for a lognormal distribution for a determined sample, but since some of the sample values are zero the logarithm goes to minus infinite. How can I solvent this dificulty to get the correct estimator? 
I have thought don't using this values but I doubt that that can be the answer.

Comment: If you really have samples from a log normal distribution, then you would need to explain why you have several observations of zero.  Is there censoring?  In other words, is there some known threshold by which observations less than the threshold are recorded as zero?